# Subset dataframe based on several conditions in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, subset

I am trying to subset a big dataframe (cyclone tracks in the northern hemisphere) on multiple conditions: data below

```
centro <- read.table("https://forms.naturwissenschaften.ch/imilast/_ERAinterim_1.5_1979_MTEX/ERAinterim_1.5_NH_M02_19790101_20121231_MTEX.txt?_ga=2.18919096.1825595846.1546710263-1112023567.1546710263", sep="", fill = T, nrows = 500,
                 header = F, skip = 2) # read here only the first 500 rows

centro <- na.omit(centro)

colnames(centro) <- c("Code","CycloneNo","StepNo","DateI10","Year","Month","Day","Time","LongE","LatN","Intensity1","Intensity2","Intensity3")
```

I want to subset only the cyclones (based on the unique column CycloneNo) that are formed in a spatial box (like -4 and 40 E longitude and 32-45 N lat) when the column StepNo == 1. Normally, this would be easy to do:

```
centro_subs <- centro[centro$LongE>=-4 & centro$LongE <= 40 & centro$LatN>= 32 & centro$LatN <= 45,]
```

However, I want to retain only the cyclones formed in this box (when the StepNo ==1) but the rest of their tracks too outside of this box.

I tried to get this by doing:

```
df_s <- centro[1,]
df_s[1,] <- NA # create an empty dataframe to be filled in the iteration


for (i in 1:length(unique(centro$CycloneNo))){
print(i)
a <- centro[centro$LongE[centro$StepNo==1]>= -4 & 
centro$LongE[centro$StepNo==1] <= 40 & 
centro$LatN[centro$StepNo==1]>= 32 & centro$LatN 
<=45[centro$StepNo==1],]
df_s <- rbind(a, df_s)
}
```

However, this ends up in an empty dataframe filled with NAs. I know this is quite hard to describe here. I feel like I am somehow close but I am also quite exhausted right now to try to figure new ways.

Comment: I don't really get your question. Your loop isn't iterating over anything (i.e no use of i). Also ... 
    centro$LatN 
    <=45[centro$StepNo==1]
returns the NA's

Comment: @Henrik - yes, sorry about that. I reduced it to 500.

Comment: @Khaynes -thanks for the heads up. I think I see now the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want a loop. I'm sure this is not the most elegant approach, but I think it works.

```
step1s <- subset(centro, StepNo == 1) # only take step 1 of all cyclones
keeps <- step1s$CycloneNo[step1s$LongE>=-4 & step1s$LongE <= 40 & step1s$LatN>= 32 & step1s$LatN <= 45] # find cyclone numbers for cyclones meeting the condition
centro_sub <- centro[centro$CycloneNo %in% keeps, ] # keep all steps of cyclones meeting the conditions
```

Answer (score 1):

Josephs provides a good answer. Alternatively one might use this in data.table, which might provide slightly more readability at the cost of some speed.

```
centro <- data.table(centro)
centro[CycloneNo %in% CycloneNo[StepNo == 1 & 
                                  LongE %between% c(-4,40) & 
                                  LatN %between% c(32,45)]]
```